# margin and size issue with the background image in tailwind css

Tags: svg, tailwind-css

I am trying to make the image to cover the whole screen but the image is cropped automatically in the section part of the code. I have tried to do `h-full` but it is not still working properly because I wanted the image to be responsive.

1st one is my error image and 2nd one is my desired image
[image: Problem Image]
[image: Solution Image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Maruti-Multi-Trade-LLC</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="">

  <header class="bg-white font-sans">
    <nav class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto">
        <div>
            <img class="w-20 cursor-pointer" src="./Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div
            class="nav-links duration-500 md:static absolute bg-white md:min-h-fit min-h-[60vh] left-0 top-[-100%] md:w-auto  w-full flex items-center px-5">
            <ul class="flex md:flex-row flex-col md:justify-end md:gap-[4vw] gap-8 list-none text-base font-bold ">
                <li>
                    <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold  " href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">RESOURCES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center gap-6">
            <ion-icon onclick="onToggleMenu(this)" name="menu" class="text-3xl cursor-pointer md:hidden"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class=" bg-[url('.\Images\BackgroundImg.jpg')] w-full h-[250px] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat mb-8 md:h-[350px]"> <---problem Part --->

  </section>

<script>
    const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links')
    function onToggleMenu(e){
        e.name = e.name === 'menu' ? 'close' : 'menu'
        navLinks.classList.toggle('top-[9%]')
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping the navigation and the section in a vertical flex layout container that is the height of the screen. Then, have the section fill the remaining vertical space left over after the navigation element by applying `flex-grow: 1` to the section:

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links')

function onToggleMenu(e) {
  e.name = e.name === 'menu' ? 'close' : 'menu'
  navLinks.classList.toggle('top-[9%]')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Maruti-Multi-Trade-LLC</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="flex flex-col h-screen mb-8">
    <header class="bg-white font-sans">
      <nav class="flex justify-between items-center w-[92%] mx-auto">
        <div>
          <img class="w-20 cursor-pointer" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFCOX.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links duration-500 md:static absolute bg-white md:min-h-fit min-h-[60vh] left-0 top-[-100%] md:w-auto  w-full flex items-center px-5">
          <ul class="flex md:flex-row flex-col md:justify-end md:gap-[4vw] gap-8 list-none text-base font-bold ">
            <li>
              <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold  " href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">RESOURCES</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="no-underline text-darkbluegray hover:text-bluegray hover:font-bold " href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center gap-6">
          <ion-icon onclick="onToggleMenu(this)" name="menu" class="text-3xl cursor-pointer md:hidden"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="bg-[url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080)] w-full grow bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat">
      <!-- problem Part --->
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bro can you please tell me how can i give the nav item to the end (with some margin in right ) as shown in the solution image.... and the the solution you provided about the background image is not responsive(the image also must get shrink in mobile view) please also tell me how can i make it responsive?

Comment: Consider positioning the nav item to the end like the solution image. Consider elaborating more on what you mean that the background image is not responsive?

Comment: I'm encountering an issue with the responsiveness of the background image on my website. On desktop, everything appears fine, but when I view the site on mobile devices, the background image gets cropped and doesn't adjust properly to fit the screen size.

Comment: How does it not "adjust properly to fit the screen size"? It should cover the full width and height of the screen not occupied by the navigation bar. I would expect the background image to get cropped, since by the looks of it, the background image seems like a landscape image while most mobile devices are held portrait.